# Doubts about mechanism of stackoverflow.com flair

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

What mechanism does stackoverflow.com flair use?
Today i discovered that this website offers profile badges or flairs to the user to put up on the website. but the url that they provide if ending with `.jpg` extension.
I guess how can a .jpg be always updated with my current profile reputations and how can it accept parameters like `?theme=clean`

Comment: Shouldn't this be on meta?

Comment: I guess this one is for meta.stackoverflow.com...

Comment: i am asking about the mechanism or technologies involved in such features of stackoverflow.com.   not about the aesthetics of the features. so why should it be on the meta version?

Comment: The wording of the question should be changed. If you're asking how it is done, it should be asked here. If you are saying something is wrong with it (which there isn't) it should be on Meta.

Comment: **PLEASE DON"T TOUCH THIS, WHILE I FILE A BUG REPORT.**

Comment: what do you mean to say? @robert?

Comment: Look at the close votes.

Comment: Bug report is here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84169/failure-to-migrate-question-to-meta

Comment: @Coding: You can't see the close votes. For some reason, there are 9 votes to close this question. Normally, 5 will automatically close (or migrate) the question. Something went wrong, hence Bob's authoritative voice.

Comment: Should this question really be on Meta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just because it has `.jpg` doesn't mean it points to a physical file.

#### Apache example

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^users/flair/image.jpg$ generate-flair.php [PT]
```

#### PHP Example

```
// Generate flair
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
// Stream generated JPEG file
```

#### Update

> your .htaccess example is okay to work with but, how do i put the part ^users/flair/image.jpg to ^users/flair/xxxxxxxxx.jpg, here xxxxxxxxx is the user_id

```
RewriteRule ^users/flair/(\d+).jpg$ generate-flair.php?id=$1 [PT]
```

Comment: your .htaccess example is okay to work with but, how do i put the part `^users/flair/image.jpg` to `^users/flair/xxxxxxxxx.jpg`, here xxxxxxxxx is the user_id.

Comment: @Coding-Freak See update.

Answer (score 4):

An extension in a URL doesn't really mean much.

You can redirect and process requests however you like.

Without knowing exactly how Stack Overflow have implemented it, I'd assume they redirect any requests to `http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/[number].png` to a script that checks if it needs to recreate the image.

If nothing has changed since the last time it was generated, it would serve a cached image, if things have changed they would regenerate the image and serve it.